# How to Solve "Could not find an option with short name "-a"

Tags: android, flutter

This is what I see when I run the below command in a [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) window:

```
cd C:\
flutter doctor -android--licenses
```

Output:

```
Could not find an option with short name "-a".
```

Comment: Use `flutter doctor --android-licenses` (be aware of dashes)

Answer (score 1):

Go to option edit configuration and check additional argument --no-sound-null-safety and option active toll window is ticked. Also run "flutter doctor --android-licenses" in terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the command in the wrong way. You need to write the command below:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

This will solve your problem.